# How would I find the solution of explicit MPC with piecewise u?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, linear-control

If I want to use this kind of system model

x(k+1)=$A$x(k)+$\overbrace{[\Phi_1\ \Phi_2]}^{B}\begin{bmatrix}
u(k)\\ 
u(k+1)\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

(Assume that the input is linearly interpolated between sample times) to solve the cost function

$J(k) = \min_u \sum_{j=1}^{N_p-1} \|x(k+j|k)\|_{Q_i}^2  +  \sum_{j=0}^{N_c-1} \|u(k+j)\|_{P_i}^2$ 
by using explicit MPC.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
x(k+1|k)\\ 
x(k+2|k) \\ 
\vdots \\ 
\vdots \\
\vdots \\  
x(k+N_p-1|k)\\ 
x(k+N_P|k) \\ 
\end{bmatrix} &= \overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
 A\\ 
 A^2\\ 
 A^3\\ 
 \vdots \\ 
 A^{N_p} 
 \end{bmatrix}}^{M_x}x(k)+\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
 B &0    &\cdots   & 0\\ 
 AB & B  & \cdots & 0\\ 
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\ 
 A^{N_{p}-1}B & A^{N_{p}-2}B & \cdots  & A^{N_{p}-N_{c}}B\end{bmatrix}}^{M_u}\begin{bmatrix}
u(k|k)\\ 
u(k+1|k) \\ 
u(k+1|k) \\ 
u(k+2|k) \\ 
\vdots \\ 
\vdots \\  
u(k+N_c-1|k)\\ 
u(k+N_c-1|k)\\ 
u(k+N_c|k) \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\label{Kostenfunktion}
\mathbf{H}&=\mathbf{M}_{u}^{T}\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{M}_{u}+\mathbf{P}\\
\mathbf{f}^T&=-\mathbf{M}_{u}^{T}\mathbf{Q}(-\mathbf{M}_{x}x_{k})\\
\mathbf{u}&=-inv(\mathbf{H})*\mathbf{f}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

should I still choose the first $u=[1\ 0\ 0\ 0... 0]^T\mathbf{u}$ as optimal input other  $u=[1\ 1\ 0\ 0... 0]^T\mathbf{u}$ during the optimization?

Comment: What do you mean by chosing the first $u$ as optimal input? Since you have an explicit optimal formula for $u$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply:) I mean, should I choose the $u=[1  1;0 0;0 0;...;0 0]u$ as the optimal control input for next iteration? Because my input is u=[u(k), u(k+1)]^T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a coordinate transformation such that it could be written into a more standard form. For your original system I use the following notation

$$
x[k+1] = A\,x[k] + B_1\,u[k] + B_2\,u[k+1] \tag{1}
$$

and the new coordinates are defined as

$$
z[k] = x[k] - B_2\,u[k]. \tag{2}
$$

Increasing the index in $(2)$ and substituting in $(1)$ gives

$$
z[k+1] = A\,x[k] + B_1\,u[k]. \tag{3}
$$

Solving $(2)$ for $x[k]$ and substituting that into $(3)$ gives the following standard form state space model

\begin{align}
z[k+1] &= A\,(z[k] + B_2\,u[k]) + B_1\,u[k], \tag{4a} \\
 &= A\,z[k] + (\underbrace{A\,B_2 + B_1}_{B})\,u[k]. \tag{4b}
\end{align}

The cost function now has to be written in terms of $z[k]$ instead of $x[k]$

$$
J(k) = \min_u \sum_{j=1}^{N_p-1} \|z[k+j|k] + B_2\,u[k+j]\|_{Q_i}^2  +  \sum_{j=0}^{N_c-1} \|u[k+j]\|_{P_i}^2, \tag{5}
$$

where the terms in the first summation can also be written as

\begin{align}
\|z[k+j|k] + B_2\,u[k+j]\|_{Q_i}^2 &= (z[k+j|k] + B_2\,u[k+j])^\top Q_i\,(z[k+j|k] + B_2\,u[k+j]), \\
 &= z[k+j|k]^\top Q\,z[k+j|k] + 2\,z[k+j|k]^\top N\,u[k+j] + u[k+j]^\top R\,u[k+j],
\end{align}

with $Q = Q_i$, $N = Q_i\,B_2$ and $R = B_2^\top Q_i\,B_2$.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really help me a lot:)